# TextAsset thinks file is ~6856 bytes when it is 120123 bytes

Tags: unity, c#, assets, resource-management, filestream

So I've created a text asset in Unity of a binary file which i'm attempting to read in as a byte array.

The result I'm getting is a byte array tht is almost half the size it's supposed to be.

The file is a serialized mesh file from here: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MeshSerializer2

What I do then is find the file unity created, move it to the assets folder and drag it into a component as a TextAsset. For smaller files it works but larger ones appear to fail to load completely.

If I load the same file separately from a C# console application using filestream it loads correctly.

Comment: When you want Unity to load a non-text file as a text asset properly, [you need to give it the file extension `.bytes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html). Did you do that?

Comment: I actually tried that shortly after making this post and it worked, feel free to put that in as an answer andI'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want Unity to load a non-text file as a text asset properly, [you need to give it the file extension `.bytes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html). Otherwise it is possible that Unity interprets certain bit sequences as the end of the file and truncates it. It is also required to allow you to access the [`bytes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset-bytes.html) property of the text asset, which you will likely need for your use-case.